# Where can I find list of words like ['Dr.', 'Mrs', 'D.C.', 'Inc.','.com'] that are to be ignored while splitting text by Period(punctuation)?

Tags: text, split, nlp, tokenize, abbreviation

I have text from huge Text/PDF file. I am working on the text to do sentence tokenization using the Period (punctuation). But, I am facing issues with cases like ['Dr.', 'Mrs', 'D.C.', 'Inc.','.com']. To deal with this, I am looking for complete list of such words. Where can I find corpus of all these prefixes/abbreviations/suffixes? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to use a segmentation library instead of trying to write something yourself. Segmentation involves more than just splitting at a period.

To answer your question though, here is a list of [English abbreviations](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter/blob/master/lib/pragmatic_segmenter/languages/common.rb).

[This README](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter/blob/master/README.md) has some additional info about segmentation and links to various research papers as well as various segmentation libraries.

Comment: The segmenter looks really good. Does it have a python wrapper?

Comment: No, that is in ruby. Python has some great natural language processing libraries. For example, try https://spacy.io/.